# In fighter jets, is the minimum speed calculated with the flaps in the down position or up?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, fixed-wing

I asked that question because F16 flying straight and level at minimum speed does not have flaps down.

So how is the minimum speed calculated by aircraft designers?

Comment: This isn't very clear and doesn't fully agree with the title.  You should edit the question to make it clearer what you're asking, then edit the title to match the question.

Answer (score 3):

In any aircraft where the flaps produce lift the minimum speed will be achieved in a flaps down configuration.

Comment: Whoever downvoted me without leaving feedback, is my answer incorrect?  It is a short simple question, it deserves a short simple answer.  P.S.  I am answering the question in the bold headline.  "How is calculated" is a separate question...

Comment: But some jets (F16 in special) in slow flight demo's don't lower the flaps  when the landing gear is up. That's why I put that question?

Comment: In doing a demo like that, having flaps down creates a high drag condition that can make the maneuver more risky, say, if thrust gets too low or you hit a bit of reduced performance wind shear at a few hundred feet, so it's done flaps up, at the minimum speed appropriate to flaps up, because it makes recovery from a low energy state much faster.

Comment: "Why do some fighter jets perform a slow flight demo with flaps up rather than flaps down?" is not the question you asked.  You need to be clear about the information you are seeking.

Comment: @MichaelHall Across Stack Exchanges, it's generally suggested not to answer a bad question.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon - I wouldn't characterize the question itself as "bad".  Poor grammar perhaps, but the main portion I chose to answer was straightforward enough.  The problem is that the question keeps morphing, and there are now actually 3 questions:  Is min speed calculated with flaps up or down?  How is min speed calculated? and Why do some fighter jets perform slow flight demo with flaps up?  OK, so maybe it is actually a bad question then...  ;)

Comment: Sorry for my grammar mistakes, my English is very poor, I learned   only in  high school and don't used to often (only  on forums , Facebook, and there's no  problem if you don't have good grammar, as you know). The F16 demo  topic was the first thing I had in mind when I put the problem here. Because the minimum speed for the F-16 is without the flaps down,When you put the flaps down the landing gear go down the nose tends to go down(so the AOA will be reduced)